# Can spare Shimano 105 chain links be used as replacement when you break a chain?

Tags: chain

A friend of mine has snapped his chain during his ride and we had to order a new Shimano HG601 chain for his 105 drivetrain. I wonder if we can use the links those will be removed from the same chain as spares if it happens again.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you talking about removable chain links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure to understand the question, correctly, but if it's about using the extra links that you got after cutting a new chain to the correct length? That would be the best source for spare links, as you are sure that they match the chain. Also if you use them after the chain is already a bit worn, the links you'd use would be potentially stronger than the ones on the bike (because they wouldn't be subject to wear). You may need additional pins though (one is sold with the chain, in case you want to use the chain without quick-link, but you need to have additional pins if you want to repair).

But, to my experience, chains break mostly at the level of outer plates. As roadside repair, I think that quick-links are much better replacements for outer plates than plates from a chain, whether new or old: no adjustment to make sure that the pin and plate are correctly aligned: you just push the pin out (if it's not already out), and install the quick link.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - more than once I've used the take-off links to extend a chain when going to a larger/lower cassette, or once when I upsized a jockey wheel.   I've also replaced some iffy sections of damaged chain with the excess links.

There's some theoretical downsides to having a couple of unworn links, but in practice it is minimal.

One trick is to buy the same chain every time, and store the excess links in the branded packaging so you know what it was.  Don't rely on your memory.